# Simplify not working, or ignoring assumption?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'm trying to take a (-1) from a power to 3/2 as this:

```
Simplify[(-(a))^(3/2) - ((-1)^(3/2) (a)^(3/2)), a > 0]
```

I get as a result as expected 0. But when I try to do exactly the same with the actual functions that I need:

```
Simplify[(-(4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2))^(3/2) - ((-1)^(3/2) (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
  a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2)^(3/2)), (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c]h) - a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2) > 0]
```

I don't get zero, I get something else... I also don't get zero using `FullSimplify`. I wonder if `Simplify` is not actually using my assumption or if there may be another reason why this is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: MMA Version 8.0 gives zero to your second `Simplify ` without problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) which will assume that all variables are real

```
Simplify[(-(4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
        a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2))^(3/
      2) - ((-1)^(3/2) (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
        a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2)^(3/2)) // 
  ComplexExpand, (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
    a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2) > 0]

(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can help Mathematica as follows. Let us replace the subexpression in question by x. This is done by the rule:

```
rule = a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2 ->x + 4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h)
```

Here is your expression:

```
expr = (-(4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
        a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2))^(3/
      2) - ((-1)^(3/2) (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
        a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2)^(3/2)) /. rule

(* I (-x)^(3/2) + x^(3/2) *)
```

Let us now simplify and replace back:

```
Simplify[expr, x > 0] /.x -> a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2 - 
   4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h)

(*  2 (-4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) + 
   a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2)^(3/2)   *)
```

Done. Have fun!

Comment: Ok, so my problem is that I would like to obtain zero after using simplify, as here:

Comment: `Simplify[(-(a))^(3/2) - ((-1)^(3/2) (a)^(3/2)), a > 0]`

Comment: The result is zero, but not when I use the other expression. I don't understand why Simplify doesn't work in that case...

Answer (score 0):

[`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSImplify.html) gives the expected result:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, h]
FullSimplify[(-(4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
     a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2))^(3/2) - 
     ((-1)^(3/2) (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - 
     a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2)^(3/2)),
   (4 b^2 E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h) - a c (1 + E^(2 Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h))^2) > 0]
```

> 0

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"